# Best SIM card for Vancouver/Whistler-Blackcomb, BC (for: phone, SMS, almost no data usage)?

Tags: canada, cellphones, vancouver, british-columbia

What would you suggest as the best SIM card for Vancouver and Whistler-Blackcomb (BC)?

Main Usage: phone calls, SMS, almost no data usage.

Comment: [Public Mobile](https://www.publicmobile.ca/en/bc/plans)

Answer (score 2):

How often will you be in Canada?  For regular but infrequent use, [Speak Out Wireless from 7-Eleven](https://www.speakout7eleven.ca/) is hard to beat.  Top-ups last for one year.  7-Elevens are easy to find throughout western Canada.

Comment: I'm relocating to BC, @Jim.

Comment: @boardrider How many voice minutes a month, and would any calls be outside BC?  How many texts?  For low usage. SpeakOut may still be your best choice.  Freedom Mobile might be attractive too if the coverage area extends to Whistler; they have a very limited network and roam on other networks in the rest of Canada.